# How to select drop down <option> by index with JavaScript where index value is grater than 325?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am unable to select index above 325 in following scenario

```
<select id="item">
 <option value="0">Some Text...</option>
 .
 .
 .
 <option value="412">Some Text...</option>
</select>

<script>
document.getElementById("item").options[412].selected = true;
// Also tried with jQuery
$('#item option')[412].selected = true;
</script>
```

Comment: What error do you get in the console?

Comment: i'm getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined"

Comment: Are you sure you have 412 options? What do you get by running `document.getElementById("item").options.length`?

Comment: yes i have option list of more then 600 items and it will increase in future. i can select upto  index 325 but above that i got error in console

Comment: What did you get from the above line of code?

Comment: i got length of 326, that is very strange, i think you sort out

Comment: Well, this suggests you have 326 options. Can you upload your full code to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Thank you very much Wais Kamal, you really solved my issue, the option list generated is actually dynamic from database, and the query return the max items 326.

Comment: Thanks, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the '.options' after selecting the element from DOM.

Following is the correct syntax:

```
    document.getElementById("item")[412].selected = true;
```